# C# LINQ - Load Entities then order them

Tags: c#, linq

The property "Orders" is not loaded ! how can I change this code to Load the property "Orders" then get its count so I can use it sort?

```
 IOrderedQueryable<Event> orderedQuery = (paging.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                                   ? searchQuery.ToList().AsQueryable<Event>().OrderBy(e => e.Orders.Count)
                                   : searchQuery.ToList()
                                                .AsQueryable<Event>()
                                                .OrderByDescending(e => e.Orders.Count);
```

Comment: I don't think "The property "Orders" is not loaded" is enough here to solve your problem. Would u give a bit more info?

Comment: Your code already appears to be getting the number of orders. What's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ToList()` executes the query and the resulting list won't contain the Orders.

It should work if you don't call `ToList()` in the first place:

```
var orderedQuery = 
    (paging.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
     ? searchQuery.OrderBy(e => e.Orders.Count)
     : searchQuery.OrderByDescending(e => e.Orders.Count);
```